# Elasticsearch Mapping Types in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-php

I want to connect to our elasticsearch Server (V7.0.0) using the official [PHP Client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php). The elasticsearch Documentation states that mapping types have been [removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) in Version 6.0.0.

But in the whole official PHP Client documentation types are still mentioned and seem necessary (e.g.):

```
// Set the index and type
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type2',
    'body' => [
        'my_type2' => [
            '_source' => [
                'enabled' => true
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'first_name' => [
                    'type' => 'keyword',
                    'analyzer' => 'standard'
                ],
                'age' => [
                    'type' => 'integer'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

// Update the index mapping
$client->indices()->putMapping($params);
```

[Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index_management.html)

Can anyone explain to me why I still have to use types when they have been removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping `types` were removed in `Elasticsearch 7.x`. In previous version (`Elasticsearch 6.x` you need to specify only ONE type per index), while in version `2.x - 5.6` you can use more than one type per index. Please check your documentation versions.

- [Removal of types [7.X]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)
- [PHP API [6.X]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index_management.html)

Since you have `Elasticsearch 6.0.0`, you need to specify mappings type, and I'm not quite sure this `API` will even work with newer version of `Elasticsearch 7.X`

Here's version matrix for `php API`:

```
Elasticsearch Version   Elasticsearch-PHP Branch
>= 6.6, < 7.0                              6.7.x
>= 6.0, < 6.6                              6.5.x
>= 5.0, < 6.0                                5.0
>= 2.0, < 5.0                         1.0 or 2.0
>= 1.0, < 2.0                         1.0 or 2.0
<= 0.90.x                                    0.4
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right. The client is not compatible yet [Source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/880)

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch 7.15 using php 8.0 version.
TO mapping the database table in Elasticsearch 7.15 in localhost

```
<?php
    require 'includes/connection.php';
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    class SearchElastic {
        
        private $elasticclient = null;
        
        public function __construct(){
            $db = new Connection();
            $this->con = $db->connect();
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($this->con); //die;
            
            $hosts = [
                'http://localhost:9200'        // SSL to localhost
            ];
            
            $this->elasticclient = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();
        }
        
        public function Mapping(){
            $params = ['index' => 'employees'];
            $response = $this->elasticclient->indices()->delete($params);
            $params = [
                'index' => 'employees',
                'body' => [             
                    'mappings' => [             
                        'properties' => [
                            'code' => [
                                'type' => 'integer'
                            ],
                            'name' => [
                                'type' => 'text'
                            ],
                            'created_at' => [
                                'type' => 'text'
                            ],
                            'last_updated' => [
                                'type' => 'text'
                            ],
                            'rank' => [
                                'type' => 'integer'
                            ],
                        ]                   
                    ]
                ]
            ];
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($params); //die;
            $this->elasticclient->indices()->create($params);

        }
        
        public function Search($query){
            $client = $this->elasticclient;
            $result = array();

            $i = 0;

            $params = [
                'index' => 'employees',
                'type'  => '_doc',
                'body'  => [
                    'query' => [
                        'match' => ['name' => $query],
                    ],
                    'size' => 9,
                    'sort' => [
                        ['rank' =>  'desc'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
            
            $query = $client->search($params);
            $hits  = sizeof($query['hits']['hits']);
            $hit   = $query['hits']['hits'];
            
            $result['searchfound'] = $hits;
            while ($i < $hits) {

                $result['result'][$i] = $query['hits']['hits'][$i]['_source'];

                $i++;
            }

            return  $result;
        }
        
        public function InsertData(){
            $this->Mapping();   
            $client = $this->elasticclient;
            $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` limit 1";
            $result = $this->con->query($stmt);
            
            $params = null;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
                $params['body'][] = array(
                  'index' => array(
                    '_index' => 'employees',
                    '_type' => '_doc',
                    '_id' => $row['id'],
                  ) ,
                );
                $params['body'][] = [
                    'id'         => $row['id'],
                    'name'         => $row['name'],
                    'created_at'   => $row['created_at'],
                    'last_updated' => $row['last_updated'],
                    'rank'         => $row['rank'],
                ];
            }
            $responses = $client->bulk($params);
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($responses); die;
            return true;
        }
        
        public function UpdateData(){      
            $client = $this->elasticclient;
            $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` limit 1, 1000";
            $result = $this->con->query($stmt);
            
            $params = null;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
                $params['body'][] = array(
                  'index' => array(
                    '_index' => 'employees',
                    '_type' => 'rules_employee',
                    '_type' => '_doc',
                    '_id' => $row['id'],
                  ) ,
                );
                $params['body'][] = [
                    'id'         => $row['id'],
                    'name'         => $row['name'],
                    'created_at'   => $row['created_at'],
                    'last_updated' => $row['last_updated'],
                    'rank'         => $row['rank'],
                ];
                
            }
            $responses = $client->bulk($params);
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($responses); die;
            return true;
        }
    }
?>
```